# JPA @Id on @OneToOne Entity with a Composite Key

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one, composite-key

I have an `@Entity` class, with an `@Id` annotation and a `@OneToOne` annotation on the same field. Usually this would not be a problem, but the entity class of the field with these annotations uses a composite key. This is causing more complications than I anticipated.

Here is the entity class that is posing the problem:

```
@Entity
public class ReportDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private MachineLine machineLine;
}
```

And here is the `MachineLine` entity class that is being used as an ID in `ReportDetails`:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MachineLine.MachineLineKey.class)
public class MachineLine {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Machine machine;

    @Id
    private long lineIndex;

    public static class MachineLineKey implements Serializable {
        private Machine machine;
        private long lineIndex;
    }
}
```

I have left out any extra fields and the getters and setters from these class definitions, to save space.

When I try to run my application it gives the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class ReportDetails] does not define an IdClass`

When I put an `@IdClass` annotation on `ReportDetails` it then requires defining the individual fields of whatever class I define in `@IdClass`, like in `MachineLine`. However, I am trying to avoid doing this, in favour of having the whole `MachineLine` entity returned whenever a `ReportDetails` entity is retrieved from the database.

Is there a way of having `MachineLine` as the ID field of `ReportDetails`, without having to define extra fields within `ReportDetails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what JPA calls a "derived identity". You might try something like this:

ReportDetails:

```
@Entity
public class ReportDetails implements Serializable {
    // all attributes map by the relationship: AttributeOverride is not allowed
    @EmbeddedId
    private MachineLine.Id id;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="machineId", referencedColumnName="machineId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="machineLineIndex", referencedColumnName="index")
    })
    @OneToOne
    private MachineLine machineLine;

    // ...
}
```

MachineLine:

```
@Entity
public class MachineLine {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    @MapsId("machineId") // maps machineId attribute of embedded id
    @ManyToOne
    private Machine machine;

    // ...

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private long machineId; // corresponds to PK type of Machine
        private long index;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Machine:

```
@Entity
public class Machine {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "machine")
    private List<MachineLine> lines;

    // ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, very much.